git filter-repo change commit author name/email
I'm trying to amend the author name/email of a commit, which the user entered the email twice. But the following error is occurring, even when I try to change commit.author_date, is there anything that can be done to overcome this problem?

Author Name: User Name User.Name@email.com
Author Email: User.Name@email.com

Error:

Parsed 1 commitsfatal: Invalid raw date "User.Name@email.com
1620394289 +0000" in ident: User Name User.Name@email.com
User.Name@email.com 1620394289 +0000


Change the commiter_date, solve the problem
